# invalid SHA-256 signature file digest

Tags: android, apk, jarsigner

I tried to sign my android application, using the command line in Linux.
When I want to check if it is signed using the command:

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs myapp__armeabi-v7a-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk
```

I got this error:

```
invalid SHA-256 signature file digest for lib/armeabi-v7a/libSDL2_image.so
```

What is wrong and what should I do?